# Finding the max. of an integral

Tags: analysis, optimization, inner-products

I have a question which asks:

Let $g\in C[-1,1]$ and the usual inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$.

Find the max value of $\int_{-1}^{1}g(x)x^3dx$ where $g$ is subject to the restrictions:

$\int_{-1}^{1} g(x)dx=0$, $ \ \ \ $  $\int_{-1}^{1} g(x)x^2dx=0$, $ \ \ \  $ $\int_{-1}^{1} |g(x)|^2dx=1$

I'm not really sure how I am supposed to proceed with this question. It is in relation to Hilbert spaces and the orthogonal projection and this question [Finding the min of an integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219592/finding-the-min-of-an-integral)

Please Help.

Comment: Don't you feel $g(x)=x$ ! `:)`

Comment: Did you try rewriting everything as a Hilbert space question?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Your comment is perfect. Mine was silly, sorry.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by re-writing everything as a Hilbert spaces question. I can see that my restrictions are requirements for an orthonormal basis but I am a bit confused as to what you mean? Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that the sup of this quantity under the given restrictions is actually the norm of the bounded linear functional $ g\longmapsto \int_{-1}^1g(x)x^3dx $ on the closed subspace $\{p_0,p_2\}^\perp$, that is the orthogonal complement of the span of $p_0(x)=1$ and $p_2(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Schwartz inequality $|<f,g>|\leq ||f||_2 ||g||_2 $.

Comment: I mean like this: “Find the maximum of $\langle g,x^3\rangle$ subject to $\langle g,1\rangle=\langle g,x^2\rangle=0$ and $\lVert g\rVert=1$.”

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes so I have that $|\langle g,x^3\rangle\leq ||x^3||=\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}$ but then I need to find out when we have equality here?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Maybe the OP is more familiar with (Cauchy)-Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint: Let $P$ be the projection on the span of $1$ and $x^2$, so $Q=I-P$ is the projection on the orthogonal complement of that space. By two of the constraints $g=Qg$, so that $\langle g,x^3\rangle=\langle Qg,x^3\rangle=\langle g,Qx^3\rangle$. So you want to compute $Qx^3$. $g$ is the unit vector with the largest possible inner product with that vector.

Comment: Isn't $Qx^3$ simply $x^3$? In that case, I am not sure how this helps.

Comment: @julien Yes, so we are doing some unnecessary work, which is fine with me. 8-)